# Is there a way I can reference only visible cells when dealing w a variable? I don't want to copy to another page if I don't have to

Tags: excel, vba

my `lrow` is correct... But I want my `Cells(I, matl.Column).Value` to only call the visible cells. Right now its calling all cells. I've tried:

`Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select(I, matl.Column).Value`
and that just gives me errors.

Lmk if this is even possible! Here's my code below!

```
lrow = Workbooks(tmpwb).Worksheets(mm).AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

For I = 3 To lrow
    'For j = 0 To 16
         session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/sub:SAPMM07M:0421/ctxtMSEG-MATNR[" & I - 3 & ",7]").Text = Cells(I, matl.Column).Value   

         

Next I
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```vb
Dim col as Range, rngVis As Range, c As Range, I As Long

Set col = Workbooks(tmpwb).Worksheets(mm).AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1)
Set rngVis = col.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

I = 3
For Each c In rngVis.Cells
    If c.Row > col.Cells(1).Row Then 'skip the header
    '   `I` below may need to be `c.row-3` ?
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/sub:SAPMM07M:0421/ctxtMSEG-MATNR[" & I - 3 & ",7]").Text = _
       c.EntireRow.Columns(matl.Column).Value
    
    I = I + 1
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Not seeing what you set c = ?

Comment: `For Each c In Rng.Cells`

Comment: Yea that gives me a 424 error

Comment: typo - should have been `rngVis`

Comment: Bingo! That worked, except its including the header as well. Can I do a For Each c + 1 type thing?

Comment: See edit above for one approach to skipping the header

Comment: Where do I put that? Directly after my For Each C?

Comment: I'm having trouble identifying where to put a then or goto statement. I am getting errors w/o it

Comment: Are you using the updated code from above?  What "errors" are you getting (error text please, not the number) ?

Comment: Yes I am using the updated code above. If c.Row > col.Cells(1).Row 'skip the header appears in red, and the error says syntax error

Comment: Missing `Then` - sorry i was writing code in the browser not in the VB editor